# Azure Cloud App File Access

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am using log4net to write out a log file for my Azure Cloud App.

I can see the log file in the browser, but cannot open it:

http://document-pdfgen.cloudapp.net/

I went through the entire Azure Portal and cannot find a way to access this file.  Has anyone done this before?

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: Your .svc file is being served, so I think IIS is prohibiting the serving of .log files. I'm not sure if there is a setting in IIS that prevents serving .log files, but another option could be that you simply need to add the MIME type to IIS so it understands how to treat a .log file: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: When you FTP into the web app do you see the log file being written?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrés Nava - .NET  mentioned that we could add the **MIME** extension **log**  MIME type **text/plain** to IIS.

For CloudService application, we could remote to Web role to set IIS by ourselves. How to remote cloudservice please refer to [Azure offical tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-new-portal).

The following detail steps:

1. Remote to corrosponding role desktop
2. Lanuch IIS manager.
3. Switch to Feature view tab and click **MIME Types**

[image]

4. add the **MIME** extension **log**  MIME type **text/plain** to IIS

[image]

5. Restart the IIS, then it should work correctly.

**Note** :According to you metioned link that you have enabled **Dirctory Browsing**. If it is not necessary we also could disable it in the IIS manager.

[image]